# Receiving a differnet HttpServletRequest from the same client?

Tags: java, rest, session, jersey

I am currently trying Java Jersey 2.23.2 for my restful service

When both of the web client and tomcat web service runs on the same device, The session was handled perfectly.

However, when the an external client (another website) that runs on a different machine, there will always be new session introduced after an API call instead of sticking to just one session.

Is there anyway I could let the external client to call the webservice just like the local client does?

Comment: Are you trying to share session between multiple client ? Look to the `jsessionid`

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that your remote client does not care about JSESSIONID cookie. When session created, server sends HTTP header Set-Cookie with it.

Client must take it and then send it back with each subsequent requests.

All browsers do it automatically.
 But as long as your client is another service it needs to care about it.